# Athena SQL - Unable to UNNEST JSON string as desired

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I've JSON string in Athena as follows:

```
[{name=agreementUrl, value=agmt-id00001}, {name=sellerOfRecord, value=ABC Corporation}]
[{name=agreementUrl, value=agmt-id00002}, {name=sellerOfRecord, value=XYZ Corporation}]
```

I'm trying to get the values of Agreement ID in separate columns Agreement ID and sellerOfRecord. With the below query I was able to get these values out but these comes in separate rows. How can I get the agreement ID and corresponding vendor in the same result record?

```
SELECT
license_metadata.name,license_metadata.value
FROM
  json_licensedata
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(licensemetadata) t (license_metadata)
```

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| agreementUrl | agmt-id00001 |
| sellerOfRecord | ABC Corporation |
| agreementUrl | agmt-id00002 |
| sellerOfRecord | XYZ Corporation |

Expected Output:

| Agreement ID | sellerOfRecord |
| --- | --- |
| agmt-id00001 | ABC Corporation |
| agmt-id00002 | XYZ Corporation |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the conditional aggregation on the dataset produced by your query :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'agreementUrl' THEN value END) as AgreementID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'sellerOfRecord' THEN value END) as sellerOfRecord
FROM (
  SELECT licensemetadata, license_metadata.name, license_metadata.value
  FROM json_licensedata
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(licensemetadata) t (license_metadata)
) as s
GROUP BY licensemetadata
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)

Comment: I've one more issue am trying to solve. If you've a chance to get to it, please  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427403/athena-sql-select-json-field-from-a-string-if-it-exists-otherwise-print-null @SelVazi