# Athena SQL - Select JSON field from a string if it exists otherwise print NULL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I've a column called Validity with JSON strings as follows:

```
{begin=2023-10-27T16:13:36.756Z, end=2026-10-27T16:13:36.756Z} 
{begin=2023-10-28T16:13:36.756Z}
```

```
SELECT validity.begin, validity.end FROM json_licensedata
```

I'm trying to print the begin and end timestamp in my query. When the end field does not exist it should print NULL. I'm trying to do CASE WHEN but it fails since the field does not exist!

Expected Output ->

| Begin | End |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-27T16:13:36.756Z | 2026-10-27T16:13:36.756Z |
| 2023-10-28T16:13:36.756Z | NULL |

Comment: What's the actual type of the column? Those are not valid json strings and the query you gave as an example is not valid syntax if the column is of type "JSON". Are they map(varchar, varchar), by any chance?

Comment: What is the result of `select typeof(validity) from json_licensedata`?